# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Installer Crash

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation, windows-installer

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2013 (over an existing 2012 install) from a handful of different ISO files, which work perfectly on other people's machines.

On mine, it will load the VS installer splash screen (just says "Visual Studio" and nothing else) for about 10-20 seconds, then shows a generic crash info window with this information :

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   VSSetup
  P1:   vs_ultimate
  P2:   12.0.30723.00.00
  P3:   12.0.30723
  P4:   Install
  P5:   unknown
  P6:   Crash: Exception
  P7:   53a12268
  P8:   2c0
  P9:   25
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
```

I get the same error no matter which installer is running (iso's came from microsoft). Tried running as administrator and got the same result.

The event log has a link to the install log file, which has lots of verbose output stuff, then these exceptions being thrown near the end :

```
[17CC:0E64][2014-10-27T12:53:27]i000: MUX:  Non-applicable packages grouped by Selectable Items:
[17CC:0E64][2014-10-27T12:53:27]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed
[17CC:0E64][2014-10-27T12:53:27]i000: MUX:  Wait for View to be loaded
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:27]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed, now create view
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:27]e000: MUX:  ERROR: The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Media.FontFamily' threw an exception.
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:27]e000: MUX:  Stack:    at System.Windows.Media.Typeface..ctor(FontFamily fontFamily, FontStyle style, FontWeight weight, FontStretch stretch)
   at MS.Internal.Text.DynamicPropertyReader.GetTypeface(DependencyObject element)
   at MS.Internal.Text.TextProperties.InitCommon(DependencyObject target)
   at MS.Internal.Text.TextProperties..ctor(FrameworkElement target, Boolean isTypographyDefaultValue)
   at System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.GetLineProperties()
   at System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.EnsureTextBlockCache()
   at System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Decorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisual()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowImpl()
   at System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindow()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Window.Show()
   at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.RunUI(ViewModelCommonUi viewModel)
   at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.InternalRun()
   at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.Run()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:27]e000: MUX:  Exception: Info: InnerException: Info:
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:27]e000: MUX:  ERROR: Not a valid Win32 FileTime.
Parameter name: fileTime
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:27]e000: MUX:  Stack:    at System.DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(Int64 fileTime)
   at System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(String path)
   at System.IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(String path)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.FontSource.GetLastWriteTimeUtc()
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.FamilyCollection.AddPhysicalFamilyToList(FontSource fontSource, List`1 familyList, SortedDictionary`2 familyNameList, SortedList`2 frequentStrings)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.FamilyCollection.BuildFamilyList(List`1& familyList, SortedDictionary`2& familyNameList, SortedList`2& frequentStrings)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.FamilyCollection.MS.Internal.FontCache.IFontCacheElement.AddToCache(CheckedPointer newPointer, ElementCacher cacher)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.HashTable.Lookup(IFontCacheElement e, Boolean add)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.CacheManager.Lookup(IFontCacheElement e)
   at System.Windows.Media.FontFamily.PreCreateDefaultFamilyCollection()
   at System.Windows.Media.FontFamily..cctor()
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:27]i000: MUX:  Metrics: ShouldSendData=False
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:27]i000: MUX:  Permission to upload: No
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:27]i000: MUX:  Preparing to serialize data.
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:27]i000: MUX:  Data serialized.
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:27]i000: MUX:  Number of SQM File queued: 1
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  SQM sent: True
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: Setting string variable 'CEIPConsent' to value ''
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: Setting string variable 'SqmOption' to value ''
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: Configuration State
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  ----------------------------
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 426 = 0
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 8 = 31
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 596 = 5.0.0.0
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 439 = vs_ultimate
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 457 = 12.0.30723.00.00
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 440 = 12.0.30723
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 573 = Rel
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 450 = 1033
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 15 = 4
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 16 = 191
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1191 = 9
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1193 = 1024
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1194 = 8192
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1189 = Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 3 = 16384
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 493 = 100733329
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 424 = 1679910
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 453 = 6.1.7601.65536
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 13 = 1033
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 841 = 0
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 438 = 1
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 616 = 0
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 494 = 
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 599 = 2
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 529 = False
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 833 = False
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 834 = False
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 563 = 810001C00000
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1063 = False
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 564 = True
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1168 = 11.0.50727.1
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 838 = 0000
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 878 = FD7FFFFFFC
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 835 = FD7FFFFFFC
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 439 = vs_ultimate
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 457 = 12.0.30723.00.00
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 440 = 12.0.30723
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 437 = 1
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 461 = 
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 517 = Crash: Exception
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 515 = 53a12268
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 501 = 2c0
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 642 = 25
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 824 = 0
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 823 = 0
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 434 = 0
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  Watson Bucketting Parameters
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  P1 - vs_ultimate
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  P2 - 12.0.30723.00.00
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  P3 - 12.0.30723
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  P4 - Install
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  P5 - 
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  P6 - Crash: Exception
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  P7 - 53a12268
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  P8 - 2c0
[17CC:1554][2014-10-27T12:53:38]i000: MUX:  P9 - 25
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong here? I'd really hate to have to reinstall my OS

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, this solved it for me. In particular the incorrect time stamps on fonts.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2978135

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Visual Studio installer can't build it's UI. You should make sure the latest version of .NET is installed and also ensure you have the latest service packs for your OS.

Comment: applied all windows updates and reinstalled .net 4.5.1... same errors :(   Thanks for the suggestion. I might have to reinstall windows.

Answer (score 0):

Gave up; Reinstalling Windows.   :[